Spring Boot - Cloud Gateway - how to store Circuit Breaker State to Redis
I have a Spring BFF, with
(i) Rate Limiter
(ii) Circuit Breaker
(iii) Time Out Limiter
(iv) Token Relay filter
(v) Retry
I am thinking of putting the BFF in an AWS Scalable Cluster Group, so my app may have multiple instances of the BFF.
I know the Token Relay stores everything in Redis. So I believe does the Rate Limiter, but what about the Circuit Breaker.
The Retry and Time Out, happen per request, so there is no state to store. But there is for the Circuit Breaker.
Here are my current yaml settings:
# spring circuitbreaker settings
circuitbreaker:
  resilience4j:
    enabled: true
    reactive:
      enabled: true
    enable-group-meter-filter: true

